# db2 alter column length named:"Group"

Tags: sql, db2, alter

"GROUP" is used as a column name wity 'CHAR' type.

I have to increase the column length, but I get this following error message.

ALTER TABLE "DB2.FAQA_GROUP" specified attributes for column "GROUP" that are not compatible with the existing column.

```
ALTER TABLE <Table-name>
ALTER COLUMN group
SET DATA TYPE char(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP` is a reserved keyword that is why you are getting syntax error. However, you can still  alter the column provided that you escape the column name with `" "`

```
ALTER TABLE <Table-name>
ALTER COLUMN "group"
SET DATA TYPE char(10)
```

Comment: Note that when you use the double-quotes, then it's going to be case-sensitive.